# What is accomplished by jQuery $(id) when id is passed as first argument of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following function, id is passed as the first argument.
The jQuery $(id) is confusing me because it has no parens or #.
What is $(id) accomplishing? 
Also, what is an equivalent native JavaScript alternative to this short function?

```
function swapColor(id, color) {
  $(id).css("background-color", color); 
}
```

Comment: It's a parameter, just like any other parameter.

Comment: Please note that various answers assume `id` is an id attribute value, and prefixing that with # makes it a css selector.  To know what can be used inside `$()` go read http://api.jquery.com/jquery/

Answer (score 1):

`id` is an argument passed into the `swapColor` function. It has to be a `string` and it has to contain the selector marker - in this particular case - a `hash sign` **`#`**, to work properly.

```js
function swapColor(id, color) {
  $(id).css("background-color", color);
}

swapColor('#box', 'blue')
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='box'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate # :

```
function swapColor(id, color) {
      $("#"+id).css("background-color", color); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the same function on many areas, and dynamically pass the `id` of the element, that you want to target and change the color. Such as,

```
swapColor("#btn", "#cececece");
```

Whereas, the other method is to hardwire the function to a specific type (or ID, or class name) and then have that type changed. The downside of that would be, that

1. Either the function itself would be hardwired to only work in that particular,

   - Case
   - Event
   - Element
2. Or even if you could get the function to be executed from anywhere else, that would only change the color of element with that particular ID. Also **note** that, in HTML it is illegal to have multiple elements target the same ID.

**One more thing**, you are not writing an event handler — click handler, or event handler, thus allowing a dynamic ID would be useful in many ways, as it allows you to run the function on *any element*.

> You need to prepend `#` to select...

True, but have a look, your code would work if you pass a class selected as well. Thus, even if you change the function declaration to the following, it would still work,

```
function swapColor(elementSelector, color) {
    $(elementSelector).css("background-color", color); 
}

/* Valid use cases
 * 1. #btn
 * 2. .btn
 * 3. button
 */
```

That is what would make this function a better case, than the following one,

```
function swapColor(color) {
   $("#myElement").css("background-color", color); 
}
```

I hope this clarifies some basic underground concepts.

Answer (score 0):

This is (almost) the equivalent in native javascript. Here however you are limited to IDS.

```
function swapColor(id, color) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Comment: Almost equivalent. The OP's function is not actually limited to IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a selector (id (#), class (.), tag) or you can pass the element itself:

```
let element = document.getElementById('element');
$(element).css('background-color', 'tomato');
```